# .htaccess redirect if contains string keeping some parameters

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm trying to redirect a route to a subdomain if it contains a certain string:

For example, if domain contains `/foo/bar/`:

`http://example.com/foo/bar/123/456.jpg` should be redirected to the subdomain `http://sub.example.com/bar/123/456.jpg`.

I mean, I would need to remove only `/foo/` from the route and redirect the result to a subdomain.

I don't know how to remove a certain string in the middle of the route keeping following strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like the following near the top of the `.htaccess` file in the root of `example.com`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^foo/(bar/\d+/\d+\.jpg)$ http://sub.example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

If the subdomain points to a completely different area of the filesystem then you can remove the `RewriteCond` directive that checks the hostname. Or if the `/foo/` prefix should always be removed (regardless of which host is requested).

This matches requests of the form `/foo/bar/<number>/<number>.jpg`.

`$1` is a backreference to the captured group in the `RewriteRule` *pattern* that specifically omits the `foo/` prefix.

This is a temporary (302) redirect.

> if domain contains `/foo/bar/`

That is part of the URL-path, not the *domain*.